# Can contour integration be applied to series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{p(z, n)}{q(z,n)}$ where $q(z,n)=0$ for possibly infinitely many $(z,n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am aware that you can use contour integration to evaluate sums of the form $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{p(n)}{q(n)}$ where $p, q$ are polynomials, $\mathrm{degree}(q) \geq \mathrm{degree}(p) + 2$ and $q$ has potentially a root at the origin. What I am wondering is that is there a version of the contour integral method which allows $q(z, n)$ to have potentially infinitely many roots at the integers. For example, take $p(z, n) \equiv 1$, $q(z, n) = (z - n)^2, z \in \mathbb{C}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $q$ vanishes at every $(n, n)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Does complex analysis offer any general enough tools to evaluate $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z - n)^2}$?

Comment: @MartinR I did mean just that, thanks for pointing this out! It is now fixed.

Comment: For fixed $z \in \Bbb C$ is $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{p(z, n)}{q(z, n)}$ of the same form as your first sum. It is not yet clear to me what you are trying to generalize.